# In YARD, can I include a file's contents in an @example block?

Tags: ruby, yard

Is there any way to do this without copy-pasting the entire file's contents?

Apparently this doesn't work:

```rb
  # @example Adding the Bing API
  #   {include:file:lib/search_engines/bing.rb}
```

If I skip the indentation, the file is rendered - but outside of the example block.

Comment: Why not just put the tag in the included file, too?

Comment: I don't think so. You can link to methods in other objects with {ObjectName#method OPTIONAL_TITLE}.